# Ubuntu not loading up graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, ubuntu-drivers

After I type in my password, I get a dialog box saying

```
The system is running in low graphics mode. 
Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself
```

On pressing OK, There are 4 options including

```
Open in terminal mode for one session
Reconfigure Input settings
Troubleshoot issues
```

None of which are working for me
I restarted my system in recovery mode. 
Got logged into the console -
Followed steps from here -
[Ubuntu forum link](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1101445.html)

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Wrote new configs on my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.
But I faced issues running

```
sudo nvidia-settings

the control display is undefined please run nvidia-settings --help for usage information
```

And rebooting my system with the `xorg.conf` changes didn't solve the problem.
What should I do to solve the issue ?